# Python debugger in VS Code cannot find external modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am unable to use the python debugger in VS Code as it is unable to find any external modules. The modules are indeed installed, in fact I get no issues when I run the python script normally. I will also note that libraries in the standard python library are unaffected.

Here is an example of an error I get:

[image]

How can I tell the python debugger where to find my external modules?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed? If so, have you selected the correct version inside of VS Code?

Comment: It looks like I have both 3.9 and 3.7. How can I check which version VS Code is using?

Comment: This seems to be most definitely the issue as I get the same error when I try to run the script with "py" (version 3.9)  whereas "python" (version 3.7) works

Comment: With the Python extension installed, try CTRL + Shift + P to open the actions menu and select the wanted Python version as the interpreter. If you start typing 'python' you should find the autocomplete you're looking for.

Comment: The active Python Interpreter should also be written on the lower left corner of the VS Code window. Clicking it should give you a prompt where you can change the active interpreter.